# UITableView on UIImageView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm creating a custom popup which consists a UIImageView on which I add some elements.
The problem is that when I add a UITableView it's not scrollable (actually it's seems not clickable as well - RowSelected event is not called).

```
customPopup = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (16, 50, 283, 499));
customPopup.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("Images/popup.png");

customPopupTableView = new UITableView (new RectangleF (0,200, 283, 220));
customPopupListSource = new CustomPopupListSource();
customPopupTableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
customPopupTableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
customPopupTableView.RowHeight = 100;

customPopupTableView.Source = customPopupListSource;

customPopup.Add (customPopupTableView);
```

Any idea what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles this issue, what solved it was adding:

```
customPopup.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
```